# Executing python module with Click command using command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, module, command-line-arguments

I have created a directory 'prince' which consists of a subdirectory 'src' containing 'main.py' file in it. This main.py uses Click command for input from user using command line. So currently I have to set current working directory to 'prince' in terminal and then execute my module using the command

'$ python -m src.main run --s 10 20 30'

where 'run', '--s' are my click command inputs.

Is there an easy way to wrap 'python -m src.main' to something short to execute my module along with inputs using click command ? Or any better way to execute my module along with inputs from user ?

Comment: You can use a simple shell script with the 'python -m src.main' and pass the params to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will answer your question.

In your src/main.py file you could add a [*#!/usr/bin/env python3* shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt) which means that your program is run by python by default.

And you should give it execute permissions via

```
chmod +x src/main.py
```

That means you can now run

```
src/main run --s 10 20 30
```

Instead of

```
$ python -m src.main run --s 10 20 30
```

---

Antother way to achieve this would be:

Create a file in the "prince" directory named "start" with Content:

```
python3 -m src.main "$@"
```

Give it executable permissions:

```
chmod +x start
```

Now you can run:

```
./start run --s 10 20 30
```